# creating overflow option (not in action bar)

Tags: android

How to create overflow menu in application. but I don't want the overflow menu in action bar. But i want it to be attached any where in the application.  I have seen one music app in which something similar is done. I want ot include it in my application. I am attaching image fro the same.

[image]
Clicking on the image.. on drop down menu will come similar to overflow menu in action bar. Can anybody tell me how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Extend [`PopupMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User117 comment was helpful and worked for me.

You can use this class and create overflow menu fron any widget.
Refer [Pop up menu link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html).

```
private void setOverflowMenu(View view)
    {
        popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view.findViewById(R.id.image_overflow));
        popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, OPTION1, Menu.NONE, "My option 1");
        popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, OPTION2, Menu.NONE, "My option 2");
        popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, OPTION3, Menu.NONE, "My option 3");
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

Called from fragment thus passed `view` as parameter. If called from activity you can directly call this method. `view.findViewById(R.id.image_overflow)` is the image from which I need to attach the menu. then Implemented `PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener` in my class which force me to implement below method

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case OPTION1:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OPTION1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case OPTION2:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OPTION2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case OPTION3:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OPTION3 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

That it. every thing works. AND don't forget to add click listener for widget(imageview in my case).